# Linking Array Properties

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a class (Winforms application) that monitors status of a group of real-life switches, and stores their open/closed status in two arrays. One array is the status in binary (0,1) format, and the other in string ("open", "closed") format. The UI uses the string format, and internal calcs use both formats, so I need both arrays.

I keep banging my head trying to figure the best way to link those two arrays, so that if the app Sets one element of either array, the corresponding array element of the other gets set automatically at the same time, in the correct format.

I've considered using some sort of Binding, but apparently Winforms won't do binding between properties, only WPF. I've also considered using the Set of each property to have logic to set the other's element (see below), but I can't figure how to configure the Set to access individual array elements (indexer maybe, though I'm not sure if that's the right path since I know nothing about them).

Here's the code I have at the moment, and of course it doesn't work because it doesn't know how to equate the array with the int in the logic statement.

Any help with a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class SystemStatus
{
    public string[] strStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return strStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            strStatus = value;
            binStatus = value == "closed" ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    public int[] binStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return binStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            binStatus = value;
            strStatus = value == 1 ? "closed" : "open";
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `strStatus` is array, hence `value` is also array, but in `binStatus = value == "closed" ? 1 : 0;` you treat it as string.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said "and of course it doesn't work because it doesn't know how to equate the array with the int in the logic statement." As a great philosopher once said, "(restating problem) != (providing solution)".  :)

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you really need, but my guess is that you have *several* switches for which you need to store both `string` and `int` values. I think you need `Dictionary` or `DataTable`.

Comment: you should use one array<T> when T is your "Switch" object, and each object has string property and a byte property for the status, also you can add a property of switch ID / mac address etc...

Comment: Again, I said "that monitors status of a group of real-life switches, and stores their open/closed status in two arrays", so yes, there are multiple switches. And I'm not sure what having an array of switches has to do with this. I merely want to maintain two arrays of statuses.

Answer (score 0):

> The UI uses the string format … so I need both arrays

I'd say the best solution is to have a single boolean array, and modify your UI code to render a Boolean as open/closed or whatever.  Post some UI code if you need help doing this, but it should be straightforward. e.g. by using an extension method like:

```
public string ToOpenClosed(this bool value)
{
    return value ? "open" : "closed";
}
```

Comment: Again, this requires that every time I need to access the UI I need to call a convert method. It seems far more efficient to do it once, automatically, as a property value conversion. That way I can just access the necessary version, bool or string, directly.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can access a single element of either array in the property's SET method? So that if I want to SET, for example, binStatus[2] in the above example it will also SET the corresponding element of the strStatus[]? I think that would solve my problem, unless someone knows of a better way to link the two arrays.

Comment: So you guys don't know the answer, but mark my question down anyways? Seriously?

Comment: @ebergerly - I didn't downvote your question.  You say "It seems far more efficient to do it once" - I disagree - I bet the performance difference won't be measurable, but can't give you more details without seeing your UI code. And you can do data binding in WinForms and implement : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding and can implement an MVC/MVP pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I can certainly use just a single binary array for status, but there are a number of reasons why I chose not to, if possible. Assume I have 10 switches. Each of those has a winforms label that displays the "open/closed" status dynamically at each timestep of the simulation I'm doing.

Comment: And I also have to bind that property to the label, so I'd also have to convert for the binding. And I'm also saving that string "open/closed" status to a log file each timestep. So each time I'd have to convert from binary to string. Plus, it makes the code more readable to use "open" or "closed" as opposed to "1" or "0". Yeah, I can do it, but it seems far easier if I can just link the two properties inside the class. In any case, the question still remains whether you can access an individual array element via SET and/or GET in a class property. Anyone know? Thanks

Comment: @ebergerly - the setter for an array property replaces the whole array, not what you want.  You could have a method something like `SetSwitch(int index, bool isOpen)`  which sets the value in both arrays at the specified index. Or have an array of custom `Switch` objects as suggested in the comment on your question from @jonathana

Answer (score 0):

not so sure about your goal but you may try this:

```
class SystemStatus
    {
        private string[] strStatus_;
        private int[] binStatus_;

        public string[] strStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return strStatus_;
            }
            set
            {
                strStatus_ = value;
                binStatus_ = new int[strStatus_.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < strStatus_.Length; i++)
                {
                    binStatus_[i] = strStatus_[i] == "closed" ? 1 : 0;
                }

            }
        }
        public int[] binStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return binStatus_;
            }
            set
            {
                binStatus_ = value;
                strStatus_ = new string[binStatus_.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < binStatus_.Length; i++)
                {
                    strStatus_[i] = binStatus_[i] == 1 ? "closed" : "open";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't this result in an endless loop/stack overflow? When you SET one array it sets the other, which sets the other, and so on?

Comment: no. try it and see. it acts on class _private_ properties

Comment: Apologies. Yeah, you're right it seems to work fine. My issue now is that when I SET a binStatus element it doesn't update and SET the corresponding strStatus element. I'm watching the binStatus, and they update fine with a SET, but the string arrays don't change as it runs thru the for loop. Can you not access individual elements of an array within a property?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this:

```
strStatus = value.Select(v => v == 1 ? "closed" : "open").ToArray();
```

And:

```
binStatus = value.Select(v => v == "closed" ? 1 : 0).ToArray();
```

A more complete solution:

```
private string[] _strStatus;
private int[] _binStatus;

public string[] strStatus
{
    get
    {
        return _strStatus;
    }
    set
    {
        _strStatus = value;
        _binStatus = value.Select(v => v == "closed" ? 1 : 0).ToArray();
    }
}
public int[] binStatus
{
    get
    {
        return _binStatus;
    }
    set
    {
        _binStatus = value;
        _strStatus = value.Select(v => v == 1 ? "closed" : "open").ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this suffers from the same problem as the other proposed solution, ie, an endless loop/stack overflow. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think so, it only sets the private backing fields with the same name as the properties but beginning with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I tried this solution also, but same as the other proposed solution, it seems to ignore the lambda expression and doesn't change any of the strStatus elements as the binStatus elements get SET. Maybe as @Joe mentioned, the setter only replaces the entire array, so it ignores any attempt to set individual elements?